# Webmatrix: Variable table name

Tags: sql, dynamic, webmatrix

I'm using Webmatrix for my project and I want to create a table in my sql-database. I tried this:

```
var createTable = "CREATE Table Table1 (mitglieder INTEGER, admin BIT)"; 
makegroup.Execute(createTable); --> this works fine.
```

But I want to have a variable table name in case which text is typed in my textfield. I tried this:

```
var name = Request["groupname"];
var createTable = "CREATE Table" +@name + "(mitglieder INTEGER, admin BIT)"; 
makegroup.Execute(createTable);
```

This doesn't work :( Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have extra space between `TABLE` and your `tableName`. Your current query will be parse as :

```
CREATE TableYour_tableName (.....)
            ^ lacking extra space
```

to fix,

```
var createTable = "CREATE Table " +@name + "(mitglieder INTEGER, admin BIT)"; 
                               ^ add extra space here
```